# SQL Take Last Row Based on Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have this kind of SQL table with different timestamp

[image]

I want to query it so it will take only the last row of each Phase. The output should be like this:

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: You say of "each phase", but then why does `Phase 1` and `Phase 2` appear twice?

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far. Also please do not post code and sample data as image. Help us to help you. Please read [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in [help]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Since the data is continuous and in sequence, I want it to select only last row. Then same phase will come again. So that's why it will appear more than one

Comment: What you have here is a gaps and island problem then.

Comment: Your records #2 and #3 have EXACTLY the same Timestamp and Phase.  This means there is no truly last record for the first group and you could get a Greentime value of 4 or 7 depending on how SQL Server decides to run your query.  Is this real, or did you make up this data and put identical timestamps by accident?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LEAD` to check the next value

```
WITH NextValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsEnd = CASE WHEN LEAD(Phase) OVER (ORDER BY Timestamp) = Phase THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
  Timestamp,
  Phase,
  greentime
FROM NextValues t
WHERE IsEnd = 1;
```